# Getting tabs information in code in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I started from the ion-tabs project, and I added a button to get the current tab information (this is obviously a simplified version of what I need to do). in Ionic3, it was enough to have

```
@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;
```

and then in the click button I had

```
 this.tabRef.getSelected();
```

and that was it - and I had the info. 
now in ionic 4 the exact same code throws an exception :

```
this.tabRef.getSelected is not a function
```

what is wrong? How do I get the tabs information in code ?

Thanks,
Yuval